# Unit test of INSERT operation in DB

Tags: c#, sql, unit-testing, testing, xunit

I have a some code for adding in my DB. It works fine, but now I need develop UNIT test for it. I have not experience with it. I'll be happy If you will give me recommendation or advice.

TESTDATAGENERATE class (here methods for tests)

```
public class TestDataGenerator
    {
        private readonly string _dataFilePath;
        private readonly Dictionary<string, List<object>> _jsonData;

        public TestDataGenerator(string dataFilePath)
        {
            _dataFilePath = dataFilePath;
            _jsonData = new Dictionary<string, List<object>>();
        }

        public void LoadData(string key)
        {
            if (!_jsonData.ContainsKey(key))
                _jsonData.Add(key, JsonUtils.GetData(_dataFilePath, key).ToList());
        }

        public List<TEntity> GetTestData<TEntity>(string mainKey, string subKey)
        {
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TEntity>>(JObject.Parse(_jsonData[mainKey][0].ToString())[subKey].ToString());

            return data;
        }
    }
```

Interface with Insert method

```
   public interface ITownRepository
    {
        Task<Town> InsertTownName(string townName);
    }
```

Implement of this Interface

```
    public class TownRepository : ITownRepository
    {
        protected readonly IConnectionFactory _connectionFactory;
        private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;

        public TownRepository( IConnectionFactory connectionFactory
                              , IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
        {
            _connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
            _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
        }

        public async Task<Town> InsertTownName(string townName)
        {

            using var connection = _connectionFactory.GetConnection();
            
            var query = File.ReadAllText(_appSettings.SQlScriptsPath + "/AddTown.sql");
     
            return await connection.QueryFirstOrDefaultAsync<Town>(query, new { townName = townName });
        }
    }
```

I have example for SEARCH query and I need develop from it my unit test with INSERT query
It's example with SEARCH

```
    public partial class ClientRepositoryTests
    {
        private class TestBuilder
        {
            public Mock<IConnectionFactory> MockConnectionFactory { get; set; }

            private readonly IOptions<AppSettings> _appSettingsOptions;

            public InMemoryDatabase _memoryDatabase;

            public TestDataGenerator TestDataGenerator;

            private const string _jsonDataPath = @"../../../TestData/Client/ClientTestData.json";

            private string _jsonDataKey;

            public TestBuilder(string jsonDataKey)
            {
                MockConnectionFactory = new Mock<IConnectionFactory>();

                _appSettingsOptions = MockSetup.GetAppSettingsOptions();

                _memoryDatabase = new InMemoryDatabase();

                MockConnectionFactory.Setup(c => c.GetConnection()).Returns(_memoryDatabase.OpenConnection());

                TestDataGenerator = new TestDataGenerator(_jsonDataPath);

                _jsonDataKey = jsonDataKey;

                TestDataGenerator.LoadData(_jsonDataKey);
            }

            public IClientRepository Build()
            {
                return new ClientRepository(MockConnectionFactory.Object
                                          , _appSettingsOptions);
            }

            public TestBuilder SetupClients()
            {
                var clients = TestDataGenerator.GetTestData<Client>(_jsonDataKey, "Clients");

                _memoryDatabase.Insert(clients);

                return this;
            }

            public TestBuilder SetupProperties()
            {
                var properties = TestDataGenerator.GetTestData<Client>(_jsonDataKey, "Properties");

                _memoryDatabase.Insert("property_published_v", properties);

                return this;
            }
        }
    }
```

Implement of GetClientBySearchCriteria

```
    public class ClientRepository : IClientRepository
    {
        protected readonly IConnectionFactory _connectionFactory;
        private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;

        public ClientRepository(IConnectionFactory connectionFactory
                              , IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings)
        {
            _connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
            _appSettings = appSettings.Value;
        }

        public async Task<IList<Client>> GetClientBySearchCriteria(string searchParameter)
        {
            using var connection = _connectionFactory.GetConnection();

            var query = File.ReadAllText(_appSettings.SQlScriptsPath + "/SearchClientAndProperties.sql");

            var parameters = new { searchParameter = "%" + searchParameter + "%" };

            var clients = await connection.QueryAsync<Client>(query, parameters);

            return clients.ToList();
        }

        public async Task<Client> GetClient(int clientId)
        {
            string query = "Select ClientName From client Where ClientId=@ClientId";
            var parameters = new { ClientId = clientId };
            using (var connection = _connectionFactory.GetConnection())
            {
                return await connection.QueryFirstAsync<Client>(query, parameters);
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is a test of search query

```
  public partial class ClientRepositoryTests
    {
        [Theory]
        [InlineData("Data")]
        public async Task GetClientBySearchCriteria_InValidInput_ReturnZeroRecords(string jsonDataKey)
        {
            var searchParameter = "5";

            var builder = new TestBuilder(jsonDataKey).SetupClients()
                                                      .SetupProperties();

            var repository = builder.Build();

            var result = await repository.GetClientBySearchCriteria(searchParameter);

            Assert.NotNull(result);
            Assert.Equal(0, result.Count);
        }
```

I tried to repeat it, but I have a problem, because I don't have experience and understanding how it works, I'll be grateful for your advice and help
My decision

```
    public partial class TownRepositoryTests
    {
        private class TestBuilder
        {
            public Mock<IConnectionFactory> MockConnectionFactory { get; set; }

            private readonly IOptions<AppSettings> _appSettingsOptions;

            public InMemoryDatabase _memoryDatabase;

            public TestDataGenerator TestDataGenerator;

            private const string _jsonDataPath = @"../../../TestData/Town/TownTestData.json";

            private string _jsonDataKey;

            public TestBuilder(string jsonDataKey)
            {
                MockConnectionFactory = new Mock<IConnectionFactory>();

                _appSettingsOptions = MockSetup.GetAppSettingsOptions();

                _memoryDatabase = new InMemoryDatabase();

                MockConnectionFactory.Setup(c => c.GetConnection()).Returns(_memoryDatabase.OpenConnection());

                TestDataGenerator = new TestDataGenerator(_jsonDataPath);

                _jsonDataKey = jsonDataKey;

                TestDataGenerator.LoadData(_jsonDataKey);
            }

            public ITownRepository Build()
            {
                return new TownRepository(MockConnectionFactory.Object
                                          , _appSettingsOptions);
            }

            public TestBuilder InsertTown()
            {
                //What I need to do here?
            }
        }
    }
```

First that I think to change in a InsertTown method I need call(before I'll do it, I need add it in TestDataGenerator) new method from TestDataGenerator, right? If it is correct, from what I need start, because I don't understand their logic, could I add insert query in TestDataGenerator?

Okay, after that I'll start to work with Tests. Could I add INSERT query here or I need add it in different place? If not, what I need to do in this part?

```
    public partial class TownRepositoryTests
    {
        [Theory]
        [InlineData("Data")]
        public async Task InsertTownName(string jsonDataKey)
        {
           ??
        }
    }
```

Comment: well.. there may be a misconception here: unit tests do not read or write to infrastructure. the concept of a unit is the smallest testable scope; which is a function.  So you're supposed to be designing tests against the conditional statements in a function and looking for signaling in your mocks.  This issue you're describing goes beyond unit testing, it is an integration test.

Comment: You should write classes you can unit test if you want to use unit tests. File.Read... is an indicator for classes/methods you cannot unit test

Comment: Okay, in my example (with search query), is it Integration test?

Comment: that doesn't this question is any less appropriate to ask or anything (but you'll probably want to revise some tags and an terms.)  But we need to verify whether your intent is to do an integration test using a unit testing framework, in this case xunit, (which may be possible, given pass through on the mocks), otherwise, answers might be completely irrelevant to your samples.

Comment: As I understood, my goal -I would repeat this test (search query), but I need change query.

Comment: well.. I don't see in your sample code what `repository.GetClientBySearchCriteria` is doing; if you're conditionally building a query in your application code.. it's not covered in your testing.  but If I presume that you're just passing the argument to be executed by sql, than yes.. the conditionality you would otherwise handle in code is actually in SQL, and therefore you'll have to do an integration test against that system in order to determine whether the result is the expected result.

Comment: I added code about GetClientBySearchCriteria